# copy text from textarea to listbox with jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [transfer data from javascript popup multiline textbox to a select control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9300978/transfer-data-from-javascript-popup-multiline-textbox-to-a-select-control)

I would like to know if its possible to copy text (one per row), from textarea and move it to listbox with some foreach loop. 
I have a textarea in a popup and a listbox where I want to put all the records from the textarea. 
Please refer to the picture for more info.
[image]
Thanks in advance and I will really appreciate if someone helps me with this. Thanks, Laziale

Comment: the explanation is little bit different, maybe this way someone might be able to help me. Thanks

Comment: I see nothing that different from the other question. Next time update your original question. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function BuildDropdownFromTextarea() {
    var lines = $('#yourTextArea').val().split('\n');

    $.each(lines, function(index,value){
      $('#yourDropdownList').append($("<option></option>").attr('value', value).text(value));
    });
}
```

Let's say you want the list to be populated on the click of a button.  Some sample markup for your button would be:

```
<input type="submit" onclick="BuildDropdownFromTextarea()" />
```

Comment: @Laziale - This code doesn't belong in the comment.  Please post it as part of your question.  To answer you question, please see the edit in my answer.

Comment: thx, works like a charm. One other thing I would like to know is what should I do, once the user will click the 'submit' button and the data gets inserted in the listbox, I want to close the jquery ui dialog automatically. The div has an ID of 'dialog'. Do you think that's possible? Thx a million for your help.

Comment: @Laziale - Have you read the documentation at all?  http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/.  It tells you how to close the dialog.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a `split('\n')` on the textarea value and use the array to populate the select box:

```
var text = $("#textareaId").val();
text.split('\n');

var selectElement = $("#selectElementId");
selectElement.find("option,optiongroup").remove(); // clear select box

foreach(var line in text) {
    selectElement.append("<option value=\"" + line + "\">" + line + "</option>");
}
```

Fastest and easy to read.